# How to create empty Array in Ada which then takes user input

Tags: ada

I would like to create an empty array in ada that takes user input to fill the array with 6 characters.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure arr is

   type ArrayType is array (Integer range<>) of Integer;
       
   Array1 : ArrayType := (67, 78, 89, 97, 45);
   Array2 : ArrayType := (45, 100, 75, 32, 99, 66);
   Array3 : ArrayType := ?????

begin

   null;

end arr;
```

Comment: You say you want to fill the array with 6 characters. Why are you declaring the array to contain Integer elements. Integer is not the same as Character. To take user input you will need to perform input. Use the Get function from Ada.Text_IO to input an individual character. Do that 6 times, putting each input into an element of your array.

Answer (score 2):

All array objects are constrained. You need to provide that constraint somehow when you declare an object of an unconstrained array type, such as your type `Arraytype`. Your first two objects take their constraint from the initialization expression (their constraints are `(Integer'First .. Integer'First + 4)` and `(Integer'First .. Integer'First + 5)` respectively). You can declare an object with default values for its 6 components in a couple of ways:

```
V1 : Arraytype (Integer'First .. Integer'First + 5);
V2 : Arraytype := (23 .. 28 => <>);
```

However, if you want your array to hold characters, you probably want to use a string type, such as type String:

```
S : String (1 .. 6);
```